Finding integer max flow in $O(m^2 \log(C))$
This is a university exam question that I couldn't answer.
Assume $N = (G,s,t,c)$ network-flow with integer capacities.
$ m = |E|, C = \max\limits_{e \in E}  c(e)$
Prove that max flow can be found in $O(m^2 \log(C))$
I tried to solve with the algorithm of finding maximum flow with maximal augmenting path in each stage, which gives complexity of $O(m^2\ln(F))$ for $F$ the value of the maximal flow.
We know that the maximal flow is at most $m C$ (because it is an upper bound of minimum cut capacity).
So we get $O(m^2\ln(mC))$. How to continue?

You are right, the c wasn't capital in the definition. $c$ is the capacity function, $C$ is the maximum of this function
